# error with autoselect for each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have edited this question to post the whole code. The problem is that only the active sheet in the workbook has the correct calculations. I have stepped through the program with many of my project workbooks, I found that the values in the columns...

```
.Range("AT2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)") 'calculating Fe weighted mean
  .Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT152")
  .Range("AU2").Value = Evaluate("2*SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((AR2:AR152-AT2)^2,$B$2:$B$152)/SUM($B$2:$B$152))/SQRT(COUNT(AQ2:AQ152))") 'calculating Fe weighted std dev
  .Range("AU2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AU2:AU152")

  .Range("AV2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AS2:AS152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)") 'calculating Cr weighted mean
  .Range("AV2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AV2:AV152")
  .Range("AW2").Value = Evaluate("2*SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((AS2:AS152-AV2)^2,$B$2:$B$152)/SUM($B$2:$B$152))/SQRT(COUNT(AQ2:AQ152))") 'calculating Cr weighted std dev
  .Range("AW2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AW2:AW152")
```

...are changing depending on which active workbook I run the code in. These 4 columns: AT, AU, AV, and AW are copied exactly from the active sheet to all the other sheets. This error propagates to give me the wrong results with the latter code lines for the other worksheets. Only the active worksheet has the correct results. So, the problem here is that there is a copy and paste of the numbers in the 4 columns of the active sheet instead of calculating the 4 equations to be used in all the other sheets and their respective data. I hope this makes sense. Please show me how to avoid this problem.

Thanks

```
Sub main()
Dim titles() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


titles() = Array("Distance (nm)", "Atom Count", "Fe %", "Cr %", "Fe (Weighted Mean)", "Fe (weighted Std error of mean)", "Cr (Weighted Mean)", "Cr(weighted Std error of mean)", "x", "Fe", "x", "Cr", "x", "Fe", "x", "Cr", "Fe Wave", "Fe Amp", "Cr Wave", "Cr Amp")

For Each ws In wb.Sheets

With ws

    .Range(.Cells(1, "AP"), .Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "BI")).ClearContents

    For i = 41 + LBound(titles()) To 41 + UBound(titles())

        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = titles(i - 41)

    Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True

End With



With ws

For i = 2 To 152
    .Cells(i, "AP").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value 'Copy distance values from col A
Next i

    .Cells(2, "AQ").Value = ""
    .Cells(3, "AQ").Value = ""
For j = 4 To 152
    .Cells(j, "AQ").Value = (1 / 4) * (.Cells(j - 2, "C").Value + 2 * .Cells(j - 1, "C").Value + .Cells(j, "C").Value) 'doing 3 point weight avg for atom counts
Next j

    .Cells(2, "AR").Value = ""
    .Cells(3, "AR").Value = ""
For j = 4 To 152
    .Cells(j, "AR").Value = (1 / 4) * (.Cells(j - 2, "E").Value + 2 * .Cells(j - 1, "E").Value + .Cells(j, "E").Value) 'doing 3 point weight avg for Fe%
Next j

    .Cells(2, "AS").Value = ""
    .Cells(3, "AS").Value = ""
For j = 4 To 152
    .Cells(j, "AS").Value = (1 / 4) * (.Cells(j - 2, "K").Value + 2 * .Cells(j - 1, "K").Value + .Cells(j, "K").Value) 'doing 3 point weight avg for Cr%
Next j

  .Range("AT2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)") 'calculating Fe weighted mean
  .Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT152")
  .Range("AU2").Value = Evaluate("2*SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((AR2:AR152-AT2)^2,$B$2:$B$152)/SUM($B$2:$B$152))/SQRT(COUNT(AQ2:AQ152))") 'calculating Fe weighted std dev
  .Range("AU2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AU2:AU152")

  .Range("AV2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AS2:AS152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)") 'calculating Cr weighted mean
  .Range("AV2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AV2:AV152")
  .Range("AW2").Value = Evaluate("2*SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((AS2:AS152-AV2)^2,$B$2:$B$152)/SUM($B$2:$B$152))/SQRT(COUNT(AQ2:AQ152))") 'calculating Cr weighted std dev
  .Range("AW2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AW2:AW152")

End With


FindAllMaxima ws 'call on another sub to find the maxima

With ws

For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp).Row
If .Cells(j + 1, "BB").Value <> "" Then
.Cells(j, "BF").Value = .Cells(j + 1, "BB").Value - .Cells(j, "BB").Value 'calculate Fe Wavelength
End If
Next j

For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "BD").End(xlUp).Row
If .Cells(j + 1, "BD").Value <> "" Then
.Cells(j, "BH").Value = .Cells(j + 1, "BD").Value - .Cells(j, "BD").Value 'calculate Cr Wavelength
End If
Next j

For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp).Row
If .Cells(j, "BB").Value <> "" Then
.Cells(j, "BG").Value = .Cells(j, "BC").Value - .Cells(j, "AT").Value 'calculate Fe Amplitude
End If
Next j

For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "BD").End(xlUp).Row
If .Cells(j, "BD").Value <> "" Then
.Cells(j, "BI").Value = .Cells(j, "BE").Value - .Cells(j, "AV").Value 'calculate Cr Amplitude
End If
Next j

End With


Next ws


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        .Range("A4") = Evaluate("SUM('" & ws.Name & "'!A1:A3)")
        'OR
        .Range("A4").Formula = "=SUM(A1:A3)"
        'Then autofill etc
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is one problem solved now. The remainder of the code has other problems that is preventing correct calculations for all the sheets besides the active sheet. I will look into it more because the code is very long and calls on other subs.

Comment: I have edited the question above because there were more problems with the code. Would you please help me solve it. Thanks!

Comment: I think rather than use Evaluate, you would be better off putting the formula in AT2 each time, then filling down and pasting values if you want to overwrite the formulae.

Comment: I dont think I quite understand your comment. How would I write the formula without Evaluate? What do you mean by: "you would be better off putting the formula in AT2 each time...."?

Comment: Have amended code above with a simple example which I hope you can apply to your situation. One alternative still uses Evaluate.

Comment: When I do the former, I still have the same problem.

Comment: When I do the former, I still have the same problem.   '.Range("AT2") = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)")' 
  '.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT152")'

Comment: When I do the latter,   '.Range("AT2").Formula = "SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)" '
  '.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT152")', another bug comes up in the code of the FindAllMaxima sub. There is a line in that code: 'MaxRow1 = NextMaximumRow(R:=R, DataCol:=.Range("AR1").Column, WMean:=.Range("AT2"), WSErr:=.Range("AU2"))', that has a bug. I think it is because I use .Range again. I have tried to debug by writing '.Range("AT2").Value', but it does not remove the bug.

Comment: For the former, you're not using the code as I posted it. For the latter, please can you update your code as it seems to be continually growing!

Comment: Ok, Let's focus on the former code because the latter one is getting bugs in the subs that I call on, which has not happened before. I do not want to post all my code because I have 5 subs that I call on and I do not want to waste your time understanding the analysis. The main problem I have here is that the values calculated equations in columns AT, AU, AV, and AW (where I find the means and standard deviations of my data) are being copied from the active sheet and being pasted in all the other sheets...

Comment: ...Therefore, at the end, all the worksheets have the same means and standard deviations despite having different data. That is where the problem is, the rest of the code works fine. I do not understand how I am not using the former code correctly as you posted. Would you please format the one below so that I can understand?

Comment: '.Range("AT2") = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)")' '.Range("AT2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("AT2:AT152")'

Comment: If you look at my answer above you will see that I incorporated the sheet name which you are not doing.

Comment: thanks for your help. It solved that particular problem, but other bugs came up. I realized my problem was not updating all the syntax when I went from "Range" for a single worksheet to ".Range" to work for all the worksheets. I had to change the syntax for all the subs and the functions within those subs for everything to work. Thank you!